# 2 fundamental questions for the Androgurus ...Can someone guide me

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have'nt plunged into Android Development as yet though Java Classes C++ all that is not new to me. Here are the questions folks. Appreciated any help on these : -

- If I need to develop test and deploy Android Apps do I NEED AN ANDROID Hardware device or is there a software Android Simulator like VMWARE or Virtual PC , where I can emulate the results.If there is such can you point me more info
- I have a Netbook ( the Chinese Ipad Clone ) running Android that has only Wi-Fi for the present. Is it possible to add the following features via the spare USB Port 
  --- a USB Based 56K Modem : Are there Android platform H/W Drivers.
  --- a USB based RJ45 ( Ethernet LAN LandLine connection ) Adapter :Are there Android platform H/W Drivers.
  Please advise
  Thanks
  Saul

Answer (score 2):

**Steps:**

1. Learn Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)
2. Do a tour on Eclipse IDE
3. Install the Android SDK
4. Go through [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409072034/http://www.vogella.de:80/articles/Android/article.html) Android on
       Eclipse Tutorial

**This is a screenshot of the Emulator:**
[image]
<sub>(source: [vogella.de](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/images/install80.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: You can use the android SDK, which includes an emulator. There you can choose your API/your Android version you want to simulate.
You can just download an embedd it to your eclipse.

To your second answer: I have no idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) For developing Android apps you can easily do it by downloading the SDK according to your specifications.Ranging from Android 1.5 to 2.2 you can download any sdk according to your requirements and target customers...As far as development goes since u are a newbie start from 1.6. Developing in eclipse IDE is quite simple than others.You can get Eclipse plugins for android. For basic testing the SDK emulator is useful.But before deployment and before adding to the market you should test it with a real device. Google G1 and Nexus1 are the favourite developer testing phones...

2)As far as the second questions goes, the issues are hardware specific too.So, better get some support from the vendors. I dont recommend messing around with the drivers. If you are quite eager to do then you might also get some help from others...